# django: create submodel for a model

Tags: python, django

[image]

How to create a model like the image where I can add as many players as I want from admin-panel?
I think players is a sub-model but I have no idea how to add multiple record at a time alongside the main model

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up the Players model as a many-to-one with the parent model and then use InlineModelAdmin to view this in the admin.

You can refer to - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Answer (score 0):

The solution is given in the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline

as Higor Rossato mentioned in the comment